# Verify if 2 LineString (shapely) are parallel

Tags: python, numpy, shapely

I have 2 `shapely.LineString`, and I would like to verify if they are parallel.

```
a = LineString(((0, 0), (0  , 1)))
b = LineString(((1, 0), (0.9, 1))) #Not intersecting, but also not parallel)
```

When I use intersects, the `intersects`, it returns `False` because the 2 lines are not intersecting, but they are also not parallel.

Is there a method in Shapely to verify parallelism? I could use the angle (via `np.arctan`).

Comment: i would just use the angle -- but remember that if the angles are 180 degrees (*pi* radians) different, they're also parallel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I came up with:

```
def isparrallel(ls1, ls2):
    xs1, xe1 = ls1.xy[0]
    ys1, ye1 = ls1.xy[1]
    xs2, xe2 = ls2.xy[0]
    ys2, ye2 = ls2.xy[1]

    if xs1 == xe1:
        angle1 = np.pi/2
    else:
        angle1 = np.arctan((ye1-ys1)/(xe1-xs1))
    if xs2 == xe2:
        angle2 = np.pi/2
    else:
        angle2 = np.arctan((ye2-ys2)/(xe2-xs2))

    return True if angle1 == angle2 else False

>> isparrallel(a,b)
True
```

Improvements are welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [(0,1), (0,0)]
b = [(0,0), (0,-1)]
c = [(2,1), (2,0)]

def is_parallel(line1, line2):
    vector_a_x = line1[1][0] - line1[0][0]
    vector_a_y = line1[1][1] - line1[0][1]
    vector_b_x = line2[1][0] - line2[0][0]
    vector_b_y = line2[1][1] - line2[0][1]
    
    if vector_a_x * vector_b_y == vector_a_y * vector_b_x:
        return True 
    else:
        return False 

is_parallel(a, b) 
# True
```